# Нет подключения к хосту с картинкой

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Скрипт для загрузки картинки. Запускаю его на локальной машине. Он скачивает картинку. Если запустить его на сервере с сайтом, то происходит ошибка. Не могу подключится к хосту с картинкой

```
<?php

$image_url = 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/download/4d0ced3c-aecd-45f9-9af3-bf735561b559';
$image_path = __DIR__."/test.jpg";

$ch = curl_init($image_url);
$fp = fopen(__DIR__ . '/my-img.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "login:pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$verbose = fopen('log.txt', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Вот лог cURL

[image: дебаг cURL]

> < HTTP/1.1 302 Found < Server: nginx/1.10.3 < Date: Thu, 30 May 2019
>   11:44:03 GMT < Content-Length: 0 < Connection: close < Cache-Control:
>   max-age=31536000, public < Location:
>   https://storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080/v1/SERVERSCOM_2ce3101fed274bd6b24d2124be063f47/image-prod/image/1cc71fdf-6290-11e8-9109-f8fc0001598d/goodimage/4d0ced3c-aecd-45f9-9af3-bf735561b559?temp_url_sig=b3df662583440bc6b16ab6f92ed55f34726eeab6&temp_url_expires=1559216703&filename=%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%99%D0%A2%20Lexus%20NX200%20NX300H%20%281%2970.jpg
>   < 
>   * Closing connection #0
>   * Issue another request to this URL: 'https://storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com:8080/v1/SERVERSCOM_2ce3101fed274bd6b24d2124be063f47/image-prod/image/1cc71fdf-6290-11e8-9109-f8fc0001598d/goodimage/4d0ced3c-aecd-45f9-9af3-bf735561b559?temp_url_sig=b3df662583440bc6b16ab6f92ed55f34726eeab6&temp_url_expires=1559216703&filename=%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%99%D0%A2%20Lexus%20NX200%20NX300H%20%281%2970.jpg'
>   * About to connect() to storage.files.mo01.cloud.servers.com port 8080 (#0)
>   *   Trying 188.42.211.42... * Connection refused
>   *   Trying 188.42.211.41... * Connection refused
>   * couldn't connect to host
>   * Closing connection #0

Пробовал выполнить запрос в Postman. Работает и возвращает картинку.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте добавить заголовок:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(    'Content-Type: application/json'));
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. На локальной машине картинка загружается, а не сервере с сайтом я не могу подключится к хосту. Ошибка в cURL как я описал в вопросе.

Comment: Добрый день!
В респонсе приходит заголовок Location, который непосредственно содержит картинку, делаете ли вы редирект на него? Postman делает редирект автоматически.

Comment: Да я делаю на него редирект, но не могу подключится к хосту. Такой же скрипт на локальной машине работает и сохраняет картинку.

Comment: Добрый день! Если проблема сохраняется, заведите Тикет в службе поддержки